# In Netlogo, can a list of boolean variables be converted from true/false to 1/0?

Tags: boolean, netlogo

I am creating a list of boolean values that represent a set of patches with the following code, where "obstacle" is a boolean property of the patch that says whether or not it is an obstacle and "map-area" is a list of specific patches.

```
set cell-walls map [ p -> [ obstacle ] of p] map-area
```

Then I print cell-walls to a text file, and it will print [ true true false true ... ]. 
I need it to print [ 1 1 0 1 ... ] instead.

Maybe I can replace elements in the list, or create a new list by iterating over this one and adding a 1 or 0 for each element. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Netlogo. Help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only ever have `true` or `false` values, you could probably get away with something like:

```
to boolean-to-numeric
  let bool [ true false true ]
  let bool2 map [ i -> ifelse-value ( i = true ) [ 1 ] [ 0 ] ] bool 
  print bool2
end
```

But do note that the above will report `0` for any values other than `true`, not just for `false`.

Comment: If you prefer it to blow up on non-booleans, replace `i = true` with just `i`

Comment: @SethTisue - Thank you for the improvement!